# База данных для тестов Java

Tags: java, база-данных, h2

Пишу приложение на java с использованием базы данных postgre sql. Свойства прописаны в файле \resourses\application.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: to_do_list
  datasource:
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/to_do_list
    username: postgres
    password: ******
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
server:
  port: 80
```

Для тестирования хочется использовать другую базу, например h2 (in memory), чтобы не трогать данные в основной. Как мне дать понять приложению, что для тестов нужна другая база? Где это можно прописать?

Comment: поидее положить такой же файл, только в ресурсы тестов(т.е. \src\test\resourses\templates\application.yml )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Благодарю @Chubatiy за комментарий. Создал файл \test\resources\application.yml со следующим содержанием:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: to_do_list
  datasource:
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:test_bd;
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
server:
  port: 80
```

Все работает как мне хотелось.

Comment: а как этот файл у вас вызывается?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, spring-boot приложение само его подцепляет. Явно где-то я не указываю, что нужно его использовать. Главное чтобы путь был верным.

Comment: Не за что. Главное что всё заработало)

Answer (score 2):

Можно пойти еще один путем. Использовать профиля для спринга:

`application.yml`:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: to_do_list
server:
  port: 80
```

`application-pg.yml`:

```
datasource:
  driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
  url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/to_do_list
  username: postgres
  password: ******
jpa:
  database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
  hibernate:
    ddl-auto: update
```

`application-h2.yml`:

```
datasource:
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:test_bd;
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
```

И потом при запуске приложения указать профиль, который будете использовать:

`-Dspring.profiles.active=h2`